# How to convert Multi-line code to single line in Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut to convert multi-line code to single line in VS Code 2018 (version 1.23) in Ubuntu.

For example convert this :

```
<label class="container-of-label">
  <input type="checkbox" class="dataTable-checkBox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

to :

```
<label class='container-of-label'><input type='checkbox' class='dataTable-checkBox'><span class='checkmark'></span></label>
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Mark code that you want to convert to single line, press <kbd>F1</kbd>, type join lines press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and voila!

You may also want to assign a keyboard shortcut for this operation. Search for `Join lines` in keyboard shortcuts list and assign the desired shortcut.

Comment: That is a great hotkey! Thanks

Comment: on mac - CTRL + J

Comment: anyone know how to set this same option in visual studio code? Its driving me nuts everytime I autosave it puts css in block format...